# How do I tell the difference between exceptions in flutter authenticating with Firebase?

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, firebase-authentication

I have Firebase a sign in for my app. I want to report exceptions to the user so he can correctly login. It is email and password sign in `signInWithEmailAndPassword(_email, _password)`. Testing I can create two exceptions which are self explanatory

1/  `Error: PlatformException(exception, There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted., null)`

2/  `Error: PlatformException(exception, The password is invalid or the user does not have a password., null)`

I'm using a `try catch block` to catch the error. Here is my code:

```
void validateAndSubmit() async {
    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
    if (validateAndSave()) {
      try {
        var auth = AuthProvider.of(context).auth;
        FirebaseUser user =
            await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(_email, _password);
        print('Signed in: ${user.uid}');
        Navigator.pop(context);
        widget.loginCallback(user);

      } catch (e) {
        print('Error: $e');
        setState(() {
          _showMessage=true;

        });
      }
    }
  }
```

I want to give a different message depending on the exception. But there doesn't seem to be any code associated with the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can catch different kind of exceptions, for each exceptions, you can check the code

```dart
  void validateAndSubmit() async {
    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
    if (validateAndSave()) {
      try {
        var auth = AuthProvider.of(context).auth;
        FirebaseUser user =
            await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(_email, _password);
        print('Signed in: ${user.uid}');
        Navigator.pop(context);
        widget.loginCallback(user);

      } on FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException catch (e) {
        print('FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException: $e');
        if (e.code === 'ERROR_USER_NOT_FOUND') {
          setState(() {
            _showMessage=true;

          });
        } else {
          // do something
        }
      }
      } on FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException catch (e) {
        // do something InvalidCredentials 
      }  catch (e) {
        // do something else
      } 
    }
```

Comment: The name 'FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException' isn't a type and can't be used in an on-catch clause.

Answer (score 1):

You can check `e.code`.
Check out native firebase [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException). It has values like 'ERROR_USER_NOT_FOUND'

Comment: This should be the accepted answer for dart/flutter apps - the different exception types only seemed to be defined for java afaik