# How To Handle Wrong Password Exception in Firebase Flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

the user can login with the correct email and password but if the email or the password are wrong the app crushes down showing this error

> Exception has occurred.
> PlatformException (PlatformException(firebase_auth, com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException: The password is invalid or the user does not have a password., {code: wrong-password, additionalData: {}, message: The password is invalid or the user does not have a password.}, null))

this is my login code as you can see i did try to catch the exception and display it but i guess with the new version of firebase this isn't working anymore.

```
    void _signInWithEmailAndPassword() async {
      if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
        setState(() {
          _isLoading = true;
          _error = '';
        });

        try {
          // Attempt to sign in with email and password
          final userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: _emailController.text.trim(),
            password: _passwordController.text,
          );

          // Navigate to home page if sign in successful
          if (userCredential.user != null) {
            final firebaseUser = userCredential.user!;
            final user = MyUser.fromFirebaseUser(firebaseUser);
            Navigator.pushReplacement(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage(user: user)),
            );
          }
        } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
          if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
            setState(() {
              _isLoading = false;
              _error = 'The password is incorrect. Please try again.';
            });
          } else if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
            setState(() {
              _isLoading = false;
              _error = 'There is no user associated with this email. The user may have been deleted.';
            });
          } else if (e.code == 'invalid-email') {
            setState(() {
              _isLoading = false;
              _error = 'The email is not valid. Please check and try again.';
            });
          } else {
            setState(() {
              _isLoading = false;
              _error = 'Something went wrong. Please try again.';
            });
          }
        } catch (e) {
          setState(() {
            _isLoading = false;
            _error = 'Something went wrong. Please try again.';
          });
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Did you consider handling `FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException` that the error message mention and as is done in the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55056608/209103?

Comment: yes i did try  FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException and i got this error The name 'FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException' isn't a type and can't be used in an on-catch clause.
Try correcting the name to match an existing class.

Comment: IT WORKS . I RAN THE APP IN RELEASE MODE AND IT WORKED!!!!

Comment: Good news @Rania.   --- I'm not sure why it would fail in debug builds and work in release mode, but... I'll take it as a win for now. :)